# Printing 2 sentences in Java,' ) expected'

Tags: java

Very novice question because that's what I am. When I compile the code below I get the following errors

1. error: ')' expected
2. error: illegal start of expression

Why won't it print ''Hello John. Would you like to play a game?''

```
class Game

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;
        String name;
        char answer;

        System.out.print("Hello! Please enter your name");
        name = EasyIn.getString();
        System.out.println("Hello!"+name"Would you like to play a game? Y/N");
        answer = EasyIn.getChar();

        if (answer = 'Y' || 'y')
        {
            System.out.print("Great! Lets play!");
        }
        else if (answer = 'N' || 'n')
        {
            System.out.print("OK, bye " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future questions, it's helpful to post which line the error occurs on — the compiler or VM usually gives a line number along with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added comments on the lines of code that had errors. I also moved a few brackets around to fit with conventional notation. Overall the code was good, you just missed a few syntactical mistakes.

```
 class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int number;
        String name;
        char answer;

    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your name"); //println not print
    name = EasyIn.getString();
    System.out.println("Hello! "+name+ "Would you like to play a game? Y/N"); // +
    answer = EasyIn.getChar();

    if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'){ // I think you we're using python 'Or'
        System.out.println("Great! Lets play!"); //println
    } else {    // Since its just Y or N, no need for another if statement
        System.out.println("OK, bye " + name); //don't forget the 'ln' on print 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
System.out.println("Hello!"+name"Would you like to play a game? Y/N");
```

You're missing a `+`. Should be:

```
System.out.println("Hello!" + name + "Would you like to play a game? Y/N");
```

Further, in your `if` and `else if` statements, both sides of the `||` need to resolve to booleans, ie.

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
```

You'll also note that instead of `=`, I'm using `==`. `=` is used to set values (assignment) whereas `==` is used to compare.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work:

```
if (answer = 'Y' || 'y')
```

Try this instead:

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

Same thing for the `N` or `n` condition. Notice that in Java the correct way to use `||` and `&&` is by writing the expression like this: condition-connector-condition. Also notice that the correct way to compare two values for equality is using `==` if they're primitive types, or `equals()` if they're object types. A single `=` performs an *assignment*, not a comparison.

Answer (score 3):

you're missing a `+`

```
System.out.println("Hello!"+name + "Would you like to play a game? Y/N");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE like Netbeans you will see red underlines appear under syntax errors in your files and a little lightbulb to the left of the line. Hover over that and you will see an explanation of the problem which will allow you to track down problems like this yourself.